# pdflatex crashes on specific word

Tags: pdftex

I cannot give example code because text is more than 300 pages. After some changes pdfLaTeX started to crash during compilation without error reporting. Trying to locate error I discovered that if I remove word **Defined** at specific place, everything is fine. Did somebody see similar case before and what kind of solution may be. Thank you

Comment: can you show the log at the point of error? (try deleting the fi )

Comment: Is there by any change a backslash before the word? Also, do you compile with `nonstopmode` or `errorstopmode`? The second one is better for debugging because it actually stops at the first error if there is any.

Comment: I use \scrolmode. And you right, it is mind to comment it in such case. Log file is incomplete because program crashed. But for the same reason I can read log file on the screen and this helped me to locate place of 'error'. There was no specific error. And I compile the same text in Russian and English and they use the same macro. Russian text does not have any error. There was time when Russian text crashed, but this was at the final point and PDF file was created. During this few hours funny thing happened. I commented this word to continue work with text.

Comment: To try your advice I remove comments and compilation was without crash. But your advise is good for future and I will use when it will happens next time. Thank you

Comment: It was not too long time before pfdlatex resumed to crash. errorstopmode did not help because there was not specific error. But because pdflatex crashes with modal box I was able to read last message **pdfendlink ended up in different nesting level than pdfstartlink** , And the error is somewhere in the middle of text

Comment: That error message could be related to the `hyperref` package. You could try to remove `hyperref` from your code and see if that solves the problem, then at least you know where to start looking for a solution.

Comment: It is possible. Or it maybe because I use hyperref and paracol. I added code \newpage before theorem where error arises, But it creates empty space before theorem. What I think about: there is no any link in theorem. However probably paracol needs to know where column starts and where column finishes and probably it uses **pdfstart/endlink** . Also it is not clear why pdflatex should crash

Comment: I little change text separating theorem and proof. At least pdflatex did not crash and I got log. The last message was **\pdfendlink ended up in different nesting level than \pdfstartl
ink
! This can't happen (pdfvlistout).
<argument> ...shipout:D \box_use:N \l_shipout_box 
                                                  \__shipout_drop_firstpage_...  
 I'm broken.** The error was shown before **\__shipout_drop_firstpage**

Comment: Is the "I'm broken" part of the error message, or is that how you feel now? (if the second, then I sympathize....) Is there anything right before the `shipout` part of the message? In any case, the pdflink error usually means that a pdf link is split across two pages, which is not allowed. If you find which link it is you can try to put it on a single page.

Comment: **Broken** is part of the message **I'm broken. Please show this to someone who can fix** .  Starting **pdfendlink** and finishing **broken** is one part of the log without any interruption. I myself is not broken, but hope to find acceptable answer. There is no link in this theorem and there is no difference between this theorem and hundred others. So this is not clear why error choose this one. If this does not crashes I can try to use trace. Maybe it will help to understand

Comment: From log file I learned that each time when hyperref  creates reference to equation or theorem, it  starts reference from macro \pdfstartlink and closes this reference by macro \pdfendlink. However directly from log is not clear which reference was source of error. No one reference was in 2 lines. Anyway, I added before theorem in question macro \newline and have smooth compilation. The same time I see that second line on the next page starts from reference to theorem. I may assume that this reference was source of error. And this reference does not have dramatic change on output